# Convergence of probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid random variables with density $(1-\cos x)/\pi x^2$.

> How do we show that
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\leq x\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\pi^{-1}\arctan x?$$

Maybe using the characteristic functions? Then
$$\phi_X(u)=\int e^{iux}(1-\cos x)/\pi x^2dx.$$ 
But how do we proceed?

Answer (score 2):

We have $(1-\cos(x)) = 2\sin^2(x),$ so your PDF is the square of a sinc function, whose Fourier transform is a [triangle function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) $1-|\mu|.$

Since the characteristic function of a sum $n$ of iid variables is the characteristic function to the n-th power, the characteristic function of $S_n/n$ is $$ \phi_{\bar X_n}(\mu) = \left(1-\frac{|\mu|}{n}\right)^n \to e^{-|\mu|}$$

And we know $e^{-|\mu|}$ is the characteristic function of the Cauchy distribution, which is the CDF you have written down.

(To see this is rigorous, one can use [Levy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).)